# Angularjs limit to directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to make a filter be used as a directive in Angularjs 1.4

What I want to make is to limit string using limitTo filter but as a directive not (|) filter.

I made this but it's not working

**charlimit.js** directive

```
function controller($scope) {
    $scope.length = 15;
}

angular.module('xApp')
  .directive('charlimit', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        limitTo: '@',
      },
      controller: ["$scope", controller]
    };
});
```

**index.html**

```
<p charlimit="5"></p>
```

Do you have any thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: Please post what you've tried so far.

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: Read the section **Creating a Directive that Manipulates the DOM** of [this guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). The `link` function gives you the power of modifying the original element.

Comment: I didn't get it exactly, can anybody helps with the example above?
I tried link property instead of controller, but it doesn't work too.

Comment: In the scope definition object you have `limitTo: '@',` but I don't see any `limit-to` attribute on the directive. And the only thing you do in the controller is to set `$scope.length = 15` which don't seems right at all.

Comment: @AlonEitan So what is the right practice is this case?

Comment: @JohnWhite I think that using native filters - You have it already, so why not use it instead? You're just adding more unnecessary processing that will slow your page

Comment: Company wise, I told them this already but they need it as a directive anyway.
Do you have any thought how to make it as a directive?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module("xApp", []);

app.directive('charLimit', function() {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var limitLength = parseInt(attrs.charLimit);
      scope.limittext = scope.limittext.substring(0, limitLength);
      return scope.limittext;
    }
  }
});


app.controller("IndexController", function($scope) {
$scope.limittext = 'Sample text';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="xApp" ng-controller="IndexController">
  <p char-limit="5">{{limittext}}</p>
</body>
```

Comment: It's not working with my example cuz I didn't have a check condition.

Comment: Ok @johnWhite .

Comment: Am using model for p tag